# Why are there many zeros on the time?

Tags: sql, oracle

INPUT:

```
INSERT INTO APPOINTMENT (A_DATETIME, CLIENT_ID, PET_ID, VN_ID) 
VALUES (TO_DATE('2023-01-20 09:30', 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi'), 1001, 10001, 801)
```

OUTPUT:

```
   APP_ID A_DATETIME                    CLIENT_ID     PET_ID      VN_ID
---------- ---------------------------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         1 20-JAN-23 09.30.00.000000000       1001      10001        801
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `A_DATETIME` column is not a `DATE` data type but a `TIMESTAMP(9)` data type and has 9 fractional digits for the seconds.

When you insert the `DATE` then it will be implicitly cast to the same data type as the column and will have fractional seconds.

```sql
CREATE TABLE APPOINTMENT (
  A_DATETIME TIMESTAMP(9),
  CLIENT_ID  NUMBER,
  PET_ID     NUMBER,
  VN_ID      NUMBER
);

INSERT INTO APPOINTMENT (A_DATETIME, CLIENT_ID, PET_ID, VN_ID)
  VALUES (TO_DATE('2023-01-20 09:30', 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi'), 1001, 10001, 801);
```

Then the table contains:

| A_DATETIME | CLIENT_ID | PET_ID | VN_ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-01-20 09:30:00.000000000 | 1001 | 10001 | 801 |

If you want to only store integer seconds then use a `DATE` or `TIMESTAMP(0)` data type:

```sql
ALTER TABLE appointment MODIFY a_datetime DATE;
```

Then the table contains:

| A_DATETIME | CLIENT_ID | PET_ID | VN_ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-01-20 09:30:00 | 1001 | 10001 | 801 |

*Note: a `DATE` column **ALWAYS** contains year, month, day, hour, minute and second components and stores it in a binary format. However, the client application (i.e. SQL*Plus, SQL Developer, Java, PHP, etc.) you are using to view the data will format that binary data  to display it and the default format it uses may only show the date components and not the time components; that does not mean the the time components do not exist, only that you need to change how the client application displays dates.*

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Hj3QIfwx)

Comment: @Johnsmith See the note in the answer and you will need to change the default settings that your client application uses to format dates to display both the date and the time components of a date. If you are using SQL\*Plus or SQL Developer then you can use `ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS';` to change the default format in your current session. If you are using a different client application then check its documentation. Alternately `SELECT TO_CHAR(a_datetime, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') as a_datetime FROM appointment;` to explicitly format the date as a string.